# I need help with code for my automated garbage bin compressor

Tags: arduino-uno

Here is my problem, I'm working on an automated garbage bin compressor. When the garbage is near the sensor, the compressor mechanism will trigger. I'm using Arduino Uno as the controller, a 12v AC window motor, an L298N motor driver, a 12v AC battery, an ultrasonic sensor, and 2 led indicators. The flow chart is as follows the sensor will detect if there is garbage in the garbage bin, if there is no garbage then the motor will not spin. If there is garbage then the motor will start spinning for 20-30 seconds and after the motor stops spinning then it will stop for 5 seconds before returning to its original position. There are 2 LED indicators, the green indicator will indicate if the motor doesn't spin and the red LED will indicate if the motor is in use. So far I'm able to program the motor to spin in 1 direction without a command to stop.

```
const int trigpin = 11;
const int echopin = 10;
int enA = 4;
int SPEED = 250;
int motordirection1 = 3;
int motordirection2 = 2; 
int duration = 0;
int distance = 0;

void setup(){
  pinMode (trigpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (echopin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (motordirection1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (motordirection2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (trigpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (echopin, INPUT);

}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite (trigpin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds (2);
  digitalWrite (trigpin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds (10);
  digitalWrite (trigpin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn (echopin, HIGH);
  distance = duration*0.034/2;

  if (distance < 1){
  digitalWrite (enA, 0);
  digitalWrite (motordirection1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (motordirection2, LOW);
  }
  else if (distance > 2 && distance <25){
  digitalWrite (enA, SPEED);
  digitalWrite (motordirection1, HIGH);
  delay (10);
  digitalWrite (motordirection2, LOW);
  delay (50);
  digitalWrite (motordirection1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (motordirection2, LOW);
  }
  else if (distance > 15){
  digitalWrite (enA, SPEED);
  digitalWrite (motordirection1, LOW);
  delay (10);
  digitalWrite (motordirection2, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  digitalWrite (motordirection1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (motordirection2, LOW);
  }
}
```

Here is the program that I have. I'm not sure if it's good or not.

EDIT: I made the adjustment in the code and it works but now the problem is the motor only moves in 1 direction when the sensor detects something but after it's out of range the motor doesn't spin back.

Comment: We can't do the work for you. Please try yourself and come back when you have a _concrete_ problem, not a whole range of problems.

Comment: `returning its original position` ... how will you know the position?

Comment: PMF - so far im able to code 2 separate program. The first program is when the program is started the motor will start spinning until the program is shutdown. The second program is to detect using the ultrasonic sensor. Based on the problem you can see that im incompetent at programming as i only started programming in this August. So yes im not very experienced in this subject

Comment: jsotola - from the question that i posted, the motor will start spinning in whatever direction for 20-30 seconds then it will simply turn back for 20-30 seconds in the opposite direction from when it started.

Comment: @Atek, are you not aware that a motor slows down when it is doing work?

Comment: @jsotola this project is still in its testing phase, that's why i need confirmation if the code i wrote is good to use or not. Im not sure what you mean by the motor slows down, do elaborate

Comment: do you not have any experience with machines? ... what about yourself, do you move just as fast when you carry a heavy weight?

Comment: the code is irrelevant ... start with some code that runs the motor in one direction ... pauses for 1 second and repeats ... change code that runs in reverse ... ... then combine the two ... etc. etc.

Comment: @jsotola I'll try to code what you just said

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> The flow chart is as follows [...]

Rather than a flow chart, you should think of your system as a [finite
state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), and draw its [state diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram).
Superficially, a state diagram may look like a flow chart, but it has
some specific properties:

- Within the states represented in the diagram, the machine does nothing
  but wait for some event to happen.
- Events trigger transitions between states.
- Whatever actions the machine may perform can only happen on state
  transitions.

Here is a state diagram that may represent your system:

[image: State diagram of an automated garbage bin compressor]

In this diagram, the actions are implicit (because I am lazy), but you
may want to write them down explicitly. For example, on the transition
IDLE → MOVING_FORWARD the motor should be started, and on the next
transition (MOVING_FORWARD → WAITING) it should be stopped.

Note also that this only represents *my understanding* of your
specifications. You will probably have to amend it in order for it to
reflect what you really want to do.

Once you have the state diagram, the next step is... to debug it! It is
essential that you do this debugging *before* you start to write any
line of code. At this stage I can already spot a couple of issues:

- One transition is conditioned on the “compressor” reaching its home
  position. This means that you will need some means to detect this
  event, like an [endstop](https://reprap.org/wiki/Mechanical_Endstop).
- After compressing some garbage... there is still garbage in the bin.
  Then, after the transition MOVING_BACK → IDLE, garbage will be
  detected, the system will immediately transition to MOVING_FORWARD,
  and it will get stuck in an endless loop.

Once you are done debugging the state diagram, **and only then**, can
you start writing the code. I suggest you follow the steps of [Majenko's
tutorial on finite state machines](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine): translating the diagram to
code should be quite straight forward.

Comment: I'll try to understand then try to implement it